# City name string(by geolocation) as variable in another function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Using Googlemap API i have extracted only city name and put it in a HTML text box. My code is

```
<body onLoad = initialize()>   
    <div ><input type="text" id="name"></div>
    <div ><input type="text" id="Cname"></div>
</body>
```

geocode

```
var geocoder;
var split1;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
}

//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng);

}

function errorFunction(){
    alert("Geocoder failed");
}

function initialize() {
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

}


function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results)
            if (results[1]) {
                split1 = results[0].formatted_address.split(',');
                //formatted address
                document.getElementById('name').value = split1[1]; //putting only city name

            } else {
                alert("No results found");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

City name is showing in 'name' text box. Now i want to copy the city name string from the text box and want to use in another 'script function as variable. But its not happening. I have missed something surely.

I have tried

```
function getting(){
   var t = document.getElementById("name").value;
   alert(t);
  }
```

But its doesn't alert dialog is not opening. I have tride with console.log but showing no string value .What should i do or what I've missed. Help me out please.

Comment: geocodint is asynchronous. You have to _use_ the variable when it exists (in the callback routine).

Comment: I think your current code is working more by luck than anything, because you don't initialise the `geocoder` variable until the `onload` event runs but you call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` immediately without waiting for the `onload`. It's only the fact that `getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous that there's enough of a delay for the `onload` to occur before `codeLatLng()` is called, and I don't think you could count on that being the case 100% of the time. You don't say when and where you try to call `getting()` from, but it would need to be after `codeLatLng()` is called.

Comment: @nnnnnn getting() is another function and calling after finishing whole geocode script. If you can then tell me any solution, or it is possible or not to use the string .

Comment: @geocodezip thnx. I've figured out the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As geocoding is asynchronous. So I have to use the responsed string variable between the asynchronous call scope. In depicted quetion I've changed it to

```
         //formatted address
            document.getElementById('name').value = split1[1];
            var t = document.getElementById("name").value;
            console.log(t);
              //do anything i want
```

Or it is more easy to use direct 'split1[1]' as string variable.